# Solve a connection refuse error in PostgreSQL database

Tags: django, postgresql

How do I solve this operational error? I have deployed my Django website and I have some issues with the database connection

my settings.py:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'avc',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': '****',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT':'5432'
        }
    }
```

I am using Postgres 10

this is the error database refused the client  request,

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecN9V.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume Django needs psycopg2 to connect

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'avc',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432'
    }
}
```

As well check if pg_hba.conf is accepting connections

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

please refer step by the step installation guide by edb
https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-postgresql-django